# How to undummy a datasset with R

Tags: r, dummy-variable

This is the libraryI am using for creating dummies

```
install.packages("fastDummies")
library(fastDummies)
```

This is the dataset

```
winners <- data.frame(
          city = c("SaoPaulito", "NewAmsterdam", "BeatifulCow"),
          year = c(1990, 2000, 1990),
          crime = 1:3)
```

Let's them create super dummies out of these cities:

```
dummy_cols(winners, select_columns = c("city"))
```

The results are

```
city year crime city_SaoPaulito city_NewAmsterdam city_BeatifulCow
1   SaoPaulito 1990     1               1                 0                0
2 NewAmsterdam 2000     2               0                 1                0
3  BeatifulCow 1990     3               0                 0                1
```

So the question if that I want to return to the previous dataset, any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(winners), crime ~ city, length)
```

---

If we need to get the input, it would be

```
subset(df1, select = 1:3)
#         city year crime
#1   SaoPaulito 1990     1
#2 NewAmsterdam 2000     2
#3  BeatifulCow 1990     3
```

---

Or with `melt`

```
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("_"))[value == 1, .(city, year, crime)]
#          city year crime
#1:   SaoPaulito 1990     1
#2: NewAmsterdam 2000     2
#3:  BeatifulCow 1990     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(city = c("SaoPaulito", "NewAmsterdam", "BeatifulCow"
), year = c(1990L, 2000L, 1990L), crime = 1:3, city_SaoPaulito = c(1L, 
0L, 0L), city_NewAmsterdam = c(0L, 1L, 0L), city_BeatifulCow = c(0L, 
0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Comment: That didn't actually return the original values.

Comment: @JoniHoppen  Now, it does

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have only one `city` as 1 in each row, you can just skip the dummy columns

```
df[, 1:3]


#           city year crime
#1   SaoPaulito 1990     1
#2 NewAmsterdam 2000     2
#3  BeatifulCow 1990     3
```

If you can have multiple cities one way using `dplyr` and `tidyr::gather` is

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key, value, starts_with("city_")) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value, -key)
```